# Fitting a curve while staying on the same side of the points

Tags: curve-fitting

What are strategies I can use to fit a curve while making sure that I stay on one side of the points? For context, I'm using `numpy.polyfit()` to find the curve today, but this doesn't satisfy the constraint of staying "inside" a region or on one side.

Comment: Would you please post a minimal working example with the minimum amount of data that will reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 1):

If I had to take a guess, it sounds like you want your function's output values to be strictly larger or smaller than the datapoints. I would check out scipy's [fitters and optimizers](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html) and especially [scipy's curve_fit](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html). A good fitting library is also [lmfit](https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/).